# How to return greater than 1, but also show 1

Tags: sql-server

I am running the below, which gives me what I need, but I also want it to show data for seq 1 if there is a seq 2, if there is no seq 2 I do not want it to return the data for seq 1. So basically i want it to return the data where the seq is greater than 1 and show me the data for seq 1

Thank you

```sql
SELECT TOP (20000)
    CPCASE.SERNO, CPCASE.DOFF, CPCASE.REGNO, CPCASE.STATUS,
    CPCASE.STATE, CPCASE.OFF1, CPCASE.FINE_TOT, CPNAME.NAME,
    CPNAME.SEQ AS nameseq, CPNAME.DKIND
FROM
    CPCASE
    INNER JOIN CPNAME ON CPCASE.SERNO = CPNAME.SERNO
WHERE
    (CPNAME.SEQ > '1') AND
    (CPNAME.DKIND = 'K') AND
    (CPCASE.STATUS = 'L')
ORDER BY
     CPCASE.SERNO
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: On what basis do you decide if you have different `SEQ`? Is it per `SERNO` or do we need to take other columns into account also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the where clause to

```sql
WHERE
    (CPNAME.SEQ > '1' OR
     EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM CPCASE C
                  INNER JOIN CPNAME N ON C.SERNO = N.SERNO
             WHERE N.SEQ = '2' AND N.DKIND = 'K' AND C.STATUS = 'L')
    ) AND
    CPNAME.DKIND = 'K' AND
    CPCASE.STATUS = 'L'
```

But know the SEQ selection works only for 1-digit numbers, since a text comparison is performed. The text `'2'` is greater than `'10'`, because `2` follows `1` in the lexical order. To avoid this problem either store the sequence in an `int` column or convert `SEQ` to an `int` before making the comparison: `CONVERT(int, CPNAME.SEQ) > 1`

Comment: Thank you very much